# Lazy way to convert log4j.xml to log4j2.xml

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

Is there a easy/lazy way (e.g a shell script etc) to convert a big log4j.xml file to [log4j2.xml equivalent](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)?

Or does everyone do this manually ?

Comment: I did it manually, but I am sure you can write an easy shell, or python script to do it. You're best best to find one already made will be to look on github for a personal project someone did to share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no tool to automatically convert log4j-1.x configurations to log4j2 configurations.

The log4j2 configuration is simpler however, and much, much better documented. The log4j2 [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html) provides lots of examples for the available [lookups](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html), [appenders](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html), [layouts](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html) and [filters](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html).

Answer (score 4):

I started writing a script to migrate simple use cases from log4j.properties to `log4j2.xml`. It is currently in a very early stage but can convert some simple configurations. It could be extended for similar `log4j.xml` configurations.

https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/log4j2-migrator

Comment: Very helpful, though a bit outdated. There was a more active [fork](https://github.com/knoguchi/log4j2-migrator), which I also [forked](https://github.com/l3ender/log4j2-migrator) and made a few enhancements. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've written a utility for converting XML to XML (log4j.xml to concise log4j2.xml). Using JAXB and FreeMarker, it makes a few assumptions about the input and doesn't support all features, but also saves comments assuming that the input file is reasonably formatted. It can hopefully be easily modified for your own requirements:

https://github.com/farnetto/log4jconverter

Comment: mvn install, then java -jar target/log4jconverter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  your-input-log4j.xml

Comment: The freemarker templates throws error   FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
 - Failed at: ${comments.log4jconfiguration}  [in template "log4j2.ftl" at line 2, column 1]

Comment: Nice. Fixed the FTL error and seems to be working fine. See: https://github.com/farnetto/log4jconverter/pull/3

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/farnetto/log4jconverter is a wonderful project. Able to migrate my log4j.xml to log4j2.xml very quickly. Great work